# Linq to xml how to get XElement by value in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Fields>
  <Field>
    <Name>DEMOFIELD</Name>
    <Category>HardwareSoftwareRequirement</Category>
  </Field>
</Fields>
```

When I do this:

```
XElement xDoc = XElement.Load("File.xml");                
var x= xDoc.Descendants("Field").Where(elem => elem.Value == "DEMOFIELD");//returns no element
```

This is not returning anything. But when I instead do this:

```
var x= xDoc.Descendants("Field").Where(elem => elem.Value.Contains( "DEMOFIELD"));//returns no element
```

On iteration, instead of `e.Value`, it returns: `DEMOFIELDHardwareSoftwareRequirement`, can't it just be `DEMOFIELD`?

And then iterate through to get the value,

```
foreach(XElement e in x)
{
    _log.Debug(e.Value);//no value here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code in the post gets node by value, but it is not the node you are looking for.

`xDoc.Descendants("Field")` selects all nodes named "Field", but that node has only child nodes. So when you call `.Value` on that node the value is computed by concatenation of all children's values ("DEMOFIELD" + "HardwareSoftwareRequirement" = "DEMOFIELDHardwareSoftwareRequirement").

Depending on what you actually looking for you either need to select all "Name" nodes and filter by value or check value of child node called "Name":

```
  var nameByValue = xDoc.Descendants("Name")
        .Where(elem => elem.Value == "DEMOFIELD");
  var fieldByChildValue = xDoc.Descendants("Field")
        .Where(elem => elem.Element("Name").Value == "DEMOFIELD");
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexei... this is what I actually missed: - selecting by Name instead of Field

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure you are comparing the value of the right elements, it's easy to get this wrong with nested XML. In your case, you are comparing the `Field` element's value (which will be all of the inner values concatenated), but you mean to compare it to the `Name` element.

Try this:

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Fields>
  <Field>
    <Name>DEMOFIELD</Name>
    <Category>HardwareSoftwareRequirement</Category>
  </Field>
</Fields>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
var x = xdoc.Descendants("Field").Where(elem => elem.Element("Name")?.Value == "DEMOFIELD");
```

You still have the `Field` element now, so you if you want to get the category you'll need to do something like:

```
x.First().Element("Category").Value
```

Comment: running your solution still gives thesame issue. When you iterate through x, and print out the value of the iterating variable, it's still:DEMOFIELDHardwareSoftwareRequirement instead of just DEMOFIELD

Comment: Yes, because we have the `Field` element, and that's the value you are printing. You'll now need to select the part you care about out of it.

Comment: Something like `x.First().Element("Category").Value`